# Подключение JavaScript в bitrix

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

В битрикс есть метод `$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript`, но в него нужно добавлять путь к файлу. А у меня не файл, а строка с JavaScript. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли метод работающий аналогично `$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript`, но получающий строку?

*При этом `$APPLICATION->AddHeadString` мне неподходит, т.к. он добавляет скрипт в документ, а не в итоговую сборку JavaScript для страницы.*
*В отдельный файл записывать строку тоже проблематично т.к. она генерируется динамически из данных...*

Comment: Вас не совсем понятно. Вам нужен `AddHeadScript` для строки, так это `AddHeadString`, который Вам не подходит, но именно он является в рамках ядра аналогом `AddHeadScript` получающим строку вместо пути к файлу. И переходите уже на новое ядро. Используйте [`\Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::addString`](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/page/asset/addstring.php) и указывайте, ему где должен расположиться Ваш скрипт.

Comment: @НиколайСарры Тут проблема не в ядре, а в том что человек хочет добавить свою строку в минифицированный/результирующий файл template.js

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужно добавлять этот кусок кода в результирующий JS файл. Он же кэшируется и получается файл будет либо перезаписываться, либо в кэше будут неактуальные данные. Поэтому просто добавьте вывод этого JS кода в footer.

footer.php:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?=$jsStr?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```